# В справке по markdown не описано экранирование символов «*» и «_»

Tags: предложение, справка, markdown

Проверил и на русском https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help и на английском
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

В справке по оригинальному markdown это описано и в главе про полужирный и курсив https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em и в отдельной главе про экранирование https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash

Считаю, что это следует добавить и в справке на SO

Answer (score 4):

Можно захотеть экранировать что угодно ещё. Например:

- backtick: `not code`
- похожий на [ссылку](example.com) синтаксис
- дефис или звездочку в начале строки, чтобы не получился список

  - раз
  - два
    - три
- точку перед числом, чтобы не получился нумерованный список

  1. раз
  2. два
     3. три
- угловую скобку в начале строки

  > это цитата

  > а это нет

В общем, если писать, то про общее правило.

> Если некоторый символ парсится как разметка Markdown, а вы хотите его в буквальном смысле — экранируйте.

---

Ну и если вы предлагаете это добавить в общую справку, задавайте вопрос на https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "если писать, то про общее правило" - почему-то Джон Грубер рушил, что в его официальной справке стоит упомянуть дважды. Хотя лично меня устроит хотя бы одно упоминание.

Comment: "если вы предлагаете это добавить в общую справку" - не особо. Просто проверял, что это не потеря при переводе, и в оригинале также.